# On an application of the Fourier transform.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to read *Exploring the toolkit of Jean Bourgain*, a beautiful article by Terrence Tao, that can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.06736.pdf), and I have what I believe to be a simple question.

Given

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \int_{S^1} 1_B(x) 1_B(x+t_j \omega ) d \sigma(\omega) dx ,$$

where $B \subset [-1,1]^2$, $1_B$ are indicator functions, $0<t_j \le 1$, and $d \sigma$ is the surface measure on the unit circle $S^1$, Tao states that, using the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) e^{2\pi i x \xi} dx $, the above double integral can be rewritten as

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} | \hat{1}_B(\xi)  |^2 \hat{\sigma}(t_j\xi) d \xi   $$

where $\hat{\sigma}(\xi) = \int_{S^1} e^{2\pi i x \xi} d \sigma( \omega) $ is the Fourier transform of the surface measure $d \sigma$. What are the steps to show this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could possibly be the solution, feedback appreciated. Note that $u(t_j\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_B(x)\mathbf{1}_B(x+t_j\omega)dx$
is an autocorrelation. Thus its Fourier transform over $\omega$ is $\hat{u}(\xi)=\hat{\mathbf{1}}_B(\xi/t_j)(\hat{\mathbf{1}}_B(\xi/t_j))^*/|t_j|^2=|\hat{\mathbf{1}}_B(\xi/t_j)|^2/|t_j|^2$ by convolution theorem and properties of the Fourier transform. The Fourier transform is a symmetric operator, thus for finite measure $\sigma$ on $S_1$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{|t_j|^2}|\hat{\mathbf{1}}_B(\xi/t_j)|^2\hat{\sigma}(\xi)d\xi=\int_{S_1}u(t_j\omega)d\sigma(\omega)$$
set $t_j\xi'=\xi$ then $\xi'=\xi/t_j$ and $d\xi'=d\xi/|t_j|^2$.

Comment: @Monolite I indicate with that the fact that $\int f(\xi)\hat{\sigma }(\xi)d\xi=\int f(\xi)(\int e^{2\pi i\langle x,\xi\rangle}d\sigma)d\xi=\int \hat{f}d\sigma$ holds for finite $\sigma $ and integrable $f$ by Tonelli-Fubini. But there is some discrepancy with $\hat{\mathbf{1}}_B$, I'm thinking about it.

Comment: The discrepancy that you talk about is that we have $\int |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2\hat{\sigma }(\xi)d\xi $ instead right?  If anyone knows how to resolve this issue do not hesitate to comment.

Comment: @Monolite no the discrepancy is that in Tao it seems like $\int f d\sigma =\int \hat{f}\hat{\sigma}d\xi$, so $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are 'switched'. The Fourier transform convention might be to blame.

Comment: Is it possible that Tao meant to write $\hat{\sigma}(\xi) = \int_{S^1} e^{-2\pi i x \xi} d \sigma( \omega) $ instead of $\hat{\sigma}(\xi) = \int_{S^1} e^{2\pi i x \xi} d \sigma( \omega) $? This might be the typo. Thank you!